# Encrypt JDBC connection to Oracle for flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

I am using flyway for Oracle database migrations. I need to enrypt the connection. I have set the `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED` and `SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=AES256` on the database side.

Now, I need to set the below connection properties for flyway to connect to DB.

```
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL, "REQUIRED");                  
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES, "(AES256)");
```

How do I specify these connection properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can set these properties and get a connection by passing these properties. Check out the samples on the [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asojbdc.htm#i1006254).